# JS editing array - result amount is incorrect and stray object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

When i click this button:

```
 const addToCart = () => {

    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_TO_CART",
      item:{
        id:id,
        name: name,
        image: image,
        price: price,
        score: score,
        releaseDate: releaseDate,
        amount: amount // this is defaulted as 1
      }
    })
  }
```

It sends it to my reducer class that stores data, im trying to edit it so it will only have a single instance of a specific item and only increase the amount

```
 case 'ADD_TO_CART':

            for (let x of state.cart){
// this should get fired if the object is found and increase amount by specified
                if (x.id === action.item.id){ 
                    let newCart1 = [...state.cart];
                    newCart1[x] = { ...newCart1[x], amount: x.amount += action.item.amount }
                        
                    return {...state, cart: [newCart1]}
                }
            }


            return {  ...state, cart: [...state.cart, action.item], };
// this should get fired if it is not found and add the whole object
```

There are two issues.

1. If I add an initial item it works (initial object) if I add a second of the same item it will increase amount to 3 instead of 2
2. On top of that it adds a "Object object" with amount 3 which I don't know what this is or how it is included given the array is of length 1 (second object)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question relates more towards an finding and resolving a bug in the code. Below is an attempt to do so.

- This line `for (let x of state.cart)` indicates that `x` is an element of the `state.cart` (an array)
- The next line: `if (x.id === action.item.id)` reinforces that `x` is not just an element, but it is probably an `object` which has a prop `id`.
- Next, `let newCart1 = [...state.cart];` indicates that `newCart1` is a shallow-copy of the object-array `state.cart`
- And here (in the next assignment) lies the problem (I think): `newCart1[x] = { ...newCart1[x].....` <--- `x` is an object and it is being used as an index to access `newCart1`. May be one needs to find the index of the matched `id` and use that here (instead of `[x]`)?

This answer may need to be updated based on further response/clarification from OP.

**Observation**

Rather than loop through the `cart` array, if it may be guaranteed that `action.item.id` will only match one item in the `cart` array, then why not just do this:

```
case 'ADD_TO_CART':
  const newCart1 = [...state.cart];
  const tgtIdx = newCart1.findIndex(({ id }) => id === action.item.id);
  if (tgtIdx >= 0 && tgtIdx < newCart1.length) {
    newCart1[tgtIdx] = {
      ...state[tgtIdx],
      amount: state.cart[tgtIdx].amount + action.item.amount
    };
    return { ...state, cart: [...newCart1]};
  };
  return { ...state, cart: [...state.cart, action.item] };
```

**Note:** The existing `for...of` loop will also only target the first occurrence as the moment it finds a match, it executes a `return` from within the loop.

Comment: Yea this is a lot cleaner, however it has one issue on stating the amount, changing it to this works perfectly: newCart1[tgtIdx] = { ...newCart1[tgtIdx], amount: newCart1[tgtIdx].amount + action.item.amount}

Answer (score 1):

```
case 'ADD_TO_CART':

            const newCart1 = [...state.cart];
            const tgtIdx = newCart1.findIndex(({ id }) => id === action.item.id);
            
            if (tgtIdx >= 0 && tgtIdx < newCart1.length) {
                newCart1[tgtIdx] = { ...newCart1[tgtIdx], amount: newCart1[tgtIdx].amount + action.item.amount}
                return { ...state, cart: [...newCart1]};
            };
            return { ...state, cart: [...state.cart, action.item] };
```